# Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException problem

Tags: azure, authentication, routes, maps

I am trying to use the Azure.Maps.Routing package in a C# application. Following the example case I set up credentials as follows:
[image]

The ClientID has been created in the Azure AD
[image]

I have the Azure Service Authentication account set to login to the same Azure AD
[image]

When I debug the app I get the following message

[image]

I am not sure what else I need to do to get authenticated. I am assuming the fact I am logged into the Azure AD through VS should allow the ClientID to be validated. Any guidance would be appreciated.

I have tried setting up the authentication as shown in the example. I am currently using Azure Maps elsewhere in the code by providing the primary key and also tried that here to authenticate without success.

Comment: I tried this against my resource, and it requires some extra steps. Have you run this command line `az login --scope https://atlas.microsoft.com/.default`? What API are you calling?

Answer (score 2):

Appears the problem was not with authentication but with pricing tier level. I tried going back to the subscription key and in the error message was a reference to not being supported at the selected pricing tier. I changed to one of the suggested tiers and everything worked as planned. Geez...better error response would have saved me 15 hours of work. I guess it knew I had lots of spare time being 80 and retired. :)